# Check for relative URLs and replace with absolutes

Tags: php, dom

I have a dynamic php code as follows

```
$url = "http://www.myweb.com/home";
$mycontents = 'These are the contents with <a href="myweb/local.php" />relative link</a> and <a href="http://www.myweb.com/home/loc.php"> absolute link</a> and some images with <img src="myweb/local.jpg" /> with relative link and <img src="http://www.myurl.com/pictures/pic.jpg" />';
```

`$url` and `$mycontents` are changing depending on the data fetched, even links contained changes. Any function that will SCAN for the variable `$mycontents` and if found any link with a or src, check first to see if is absolute, if yes, leave it, if no, using str_replace `str_replace("src=\"", "src=\"".$url, $mycontents)` and change all links before echoing $mycontents, Target is, once $mycontents get echoed, has to be modified with all relative links scanned and found changed to absolute.

Comment: i am fetching data from several sites, from which their contents may contain either Relative or absolute link, the site url is available as $url above shows, but before echoing $mycontents, Links and images have to be checked for relative or absolute Url, if Relative, change to Absolute, and if Absolute, leave it as it is.. Help Please i am stuck now..

Answer (score 0):

First you should identify exactly what attributes you need to be looking for and checking their values. The simplest check of course is to simply look for URLcontaining `http(s)://` at the beginning of them and classing them as absolute already, anything else needs to be replaced.

These attributes would be `href` and `src`, as a base.

Of course, it's a very rudimentary check but it should suit your needs at least for now, barring any edge cases that may arise.

Comment: Any PHP function to check and make changes for that PLEASEEE....my head is aching!

Comment: You could use a regular expression to locate and identify the strings that needed replacing. Look into [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

Comment: I think this is more complex than you really need but it pulls out what I'd expect from a few test strings: `#(href|src)=(.)(((?!http\:)[a-z0-9\/\\\.])*)\2#i`